# How to select closest hidden div in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to perform a keypress event the divs inside the bus_lines div.

```
$('#bus_lines').keypress(function(e){
    var box = $(this).closest("div:hidden").attr("id");
    console.log(box);

});
```

Here's what it looks like in firebug:

[image]

It only works on the parent div which is the one with the bus_lines id. If I try to perform keypress events inside of fs_buslines or fs_bustax its not working. I need to know the closest div where the keypress is performed. Basically I'm trying to perform button click events using keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`closest` searches through an element's ancestors.  It looks like you're looking for the first descendant of the current element that matches a selector.  As a result, you want `find`

```
var box = $(this).find("div:hidden:first").attr("id");
```

Comment: those buttons are  inside of the divs inside bus_lines. The previous div will be set to hide and the next div is set to show. What I want the variable box to store is either fs_buslines, fs_bustax, fs_regfees, or summary. But all the selectors that I tried so far yields me the bus_lines div or even the parent of the bus_lines div.

Comment: @KyokaSuigetsu - I'm really not sure.  I thought the above answered your question.  Maybe post a new question with a more thorough example?

Comment: @KyokaSuigetsu Adams answer is correct. You can check out the jsfiddle I made that shows his selector working. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PdZKe/)